# How to call JSR223 Preprocessor in Jmeter only once for each request

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

In am using JSR 223 Preprocessor in my script. In script there is one API with the body data as below:

```
{`"key":"appStorage","value":"{\"model_sta10:\":\"{\\\"StratSim_Controls!R15C5\\\":\\\"10\\\",\\\"Inputs_Main!R23C5\\\":\\\"10amname\\\"}\",\"return_url\":\"/main/welcome-screen\",\`round_value`\":\"1\",\"round-one-star10d\":\"true\",\"intro-comple10\":\"true\"}"}
```

But when I execute the script it is not working getting the error and one slack got removed from the response.

So I added the JSR 223 preprocessor with below code for request:

```
`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase
def request = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
request = request.replace('te',vars.get('te')).replace('teamname', vars.get('teamname'))
def arguments = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments();
sampler.setArguments(arguments);
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',request,'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
`
```

and pass the parameter in body:

```
{"key":"appStorage","value":"{\"model_state:\":\"{\\\"StratSim_Controls!R15C5\\\":\\\"te\\\",\\\"Inputs_Main!R23C5\\\":\\\"teamname\\\"}\",\"return_url\":\"/main/welcome-screen\",\"round_value\":\"1\",\"round-one-started\":\"true\",\"intro-complete\":\"true\"}"}
`
```

But in script this request are present multiple times and I have to add JSR 223 preprocessor in each request, Do we have any solution that we can use the code only once for all request?

I tried with solution where I added the JSR223 preprocessor in the thread group but it is not working getting the error for getCalue().

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is at least one Sampler in the JSR223 PreProcessor's [Scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) which doesn't have a request body, i.e. you're sending a [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request without parameters.

You can use `sampler` shorthand and some [`if` conditional structure](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_if_else) to:

- check whether the current `sampler` is a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
- check whether it has at least 1 argument

Something like:

```
if (sampler instanceof org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy) {
    if (sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0) != null) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

If you put the JSR223 PreProcessor on Thread Group level it will be executed before each Sampler in the Thread Group so you might want to come up with more conditions to filter out the unwanted executions.

More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates)